# Bootstrap 3's DateTimePicker defaultDate from HTML markup

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-datetimepicker

With [Bootstrap 3 DateTimePicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/), I understand that [defaultDate](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#defaultdate) can be configured via JS. Is it not possible to use the value of the input field as default?

Not working:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="2016-01-15" data-date-format="L" />
```

[Here's a JSFiddle attempt](http://jsfiddle.net/u1rm2vmm/3/) that is not working.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes you can use value but I think the format you are using isn't correct so it doesn't display. Change value to `value="15-01-2016"` and it should display

Comment: Thanks, Will that worked. This means the date string for value has to be formatted according to the locale? Do you know if it's explained anywhere in detail?

Comment: As far as i'm aware it has to be the same format as the locale, if anybody knows otherwise then please say. Unfortunately I don't know of any useful resources explaining this sorry

Comment: I managed confirm that a `dp.error` is emitted (http://jsfiddle.net/u1rm2vmm/10/), but I'm unsure if it's possible to override parseInputDate (https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/blob/master/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js#L2155) to change the behaviour. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`format: 'L'` is the same as `format: 'MM/DD/YYYY` your textbox value does not match this format and thus is an "invalid date".

If you need other formats to be valid us [`extraFormats`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#extraformats)

Comment: Using extraFormats was exactly what I was looking for http://jsfiddle.net/u1rm2vmm/11/